# How to avoid 502 with node/nginx from the other side of the world?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have someone in Pakistan helping me with data entry and no matter what browser or connection type (he's tried US VPNs), he gets a stream of 502 errors when loading the site. He sometimes gets a few minutes (or recently a few weeks) where he can access the site without issues.

I was accessing his system via TeamViewer and the resources that were returning 502 were totally fine when accessed directly. For instance, an image that was failing inside the app, loaded with no issues in a separate tab.

I'm guessing there's some kind of setting in nginx or node where I can increase the amount of time before the connection closes.

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
# user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

And server.js:

```
// --- Express ---
var pmx = require('pmx').init();
var winston = require('winston');
pmx.http();

var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
var compression = require('compression');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var path = require('path');

var assetManager = require('connect-assetmanager');
var siteConfig = require('./config/server_config.js');
var assetManagerGroups = require('./compressed_assets.js');

var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

// socket = require('./chatserver');
var hapzis = require('./app/hapzis.js');
var router = require('./router');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

// --- Auth Config ---
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});

// --- Static Files ---
app.use(compression());
var assetsManagerMiddleware = assetManager(assetManagerGroups);
app.use('/', assetsManagerMiddleware, express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


// --- view engine setup ---
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs-locals'));
app.set("x-powered-by", false);
app.locals._ = require("lodash");

// --- Config ---
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || siteConfig.port);
process.env.TZ = 'US/Pacific';
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method'));         // Microsoft
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // Google/GData
app.use(methodOverride('X-Method-Override'));      // IBM
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: __dirname + "/public/uploads" }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    name: "hapzis.sid",
    secret: "********",
    resave: false, //don't save session if unmodified
    saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something stored
    store: new MongoStore({ // uses `sessions` collection
      url: siteConfig.mongodbConnectionString,
      touchAfter: 24 * 3600
    }),
    rolling: true, // reset expiration date on response
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 2592000000 // 1 month
    }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', {maxAge: 2592000000}));

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if ('development' === env) {
    app.use(errorHandler());
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    winston.cli();
}


// --- Routes ---
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));
app.use('/admin', require('./routes/admin'));
router.route(app); // Todo: Clean this up into other routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/helper'));
app.use('/', require('./routes/landing'));


// --- 404 & Errors ---

app.use(pmx.expressErrorHandler());

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res) {
  var err = new Error("Not Found");
  err.status = 404;
  err.path = req.url;
  res.status(err.status || 500);

  var message = err.message;
  var stack = err;
  if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
    stack = null;
  }

  res.render('error', {
    message: message,
    error: stack
  });
});


server.listen(siteConfig.port);
hapzis.logger.log("info", siteConfig.serverStartedMsg);

module.exports = app;
```

sites-enabled/hapzis

```
upstream app_hapzis {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

upstream app_dev {
  server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.hapzis.com;

    location ~ ^/(uploads/) {
       root /home/ubuntu/hapzis/public;
       access_log off;
       expires max;
    }

    location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                proxy_pass http://app_dev;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.hapzis.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://hapzis.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name hapzis.com;

  proxy_connect_timeout       600s;
  proxy_send_timeout          600s;
  proxy_read_timeout          600s;
  send_timeout                600s;
    location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                proxy_pass http://app_hapzis;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

}
```

Comment: Are you using nginx as an rproxy for a node.js server? If that's the case you should post the corresponding configuration file (the one in sites-enabled that describes the connection between nginx and the node.js server).

Comment: Great! I've added the file above.

Comment: The timeouts look generous enough (although I would recommend to specify the timeunit explicitly anyways, if not specified nginx assumes seconds - ie `proxy_send_timeout 600s;` instead of just `proxy_send_timeout 600;` to avoid confusion)

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it's still failing for him and others on his team (in different countries but in the same-ish region)

Comment: Also, it seems like the first time users load (via a private window, for instance) the site works. If they reload the page, it usually has this issue. The site is a single-page app via backbone.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue ended up being that an error was causing the node server to terminate and pm2 was rebooting it. I'm still not sure why it was only affecting some users, but being new to pm2/nginx/node I was having trouble with the logs.